# How to differentiate fields being populated from popup

Tags: javascript, html, tapestry

I have a popup window that is used to search through a database for specific users. On the parent page I have multiple fields that populate from the same popup. My question is how can I differentiate or be able to tell which button the popup was launched from so as to populate the correct field.

Examples of the textfields:

```
<input t:type="textfield" id="resolveUser" t:id="resolveUser" style="display:none;"/> 
<input type="button" id="change" style="display:none;" 
                            onclick="window.open(removed to keep it short)" value="Search Users" /><br/><br/>

<input t:type="textfield" t:id="assignUser" id="assignUser" validate="required"/> 
<input type="button" id="change" 
                            onclick="window.open(removed to keep it short)"  value="SearchUsers" /><br/><br/>
```

There is javascript attatched to grab the values from the popup. I imagine that the logic to do this will have to be added in that block?

```
function updateFromUser(login, first, last, email, id){
                    complaintForm = document.forms['updateForm'];
                    var assignTo = document.getElementById("assignUser");
                    var resolveBy = document.getElementById("resolveUser");

                    assignTo.value = login;
                    resolveBy.value = login;
```

Of course the way it stands both fields get the value which is less than desirable. I fiddled with the js but my logic could not cover a scenario in which both fields were blank.

Comment: The basic idea is to store the target in a variable when opening the popup, then fill in the proper fields depending on its value. However, you assigned a "java" tag to this question, you're using `window.open` and have apparently never heard of jQuery. Not sure you're ready to ask questions on stack overflow, to be honest. Sorry.

Comment: @ChrisG page is part of a tapestry program. Didn't just throw java in there out of left field although it may not be in the immediate scope of the question.

Comment: Java has no relevance to the Q whatsoever. And what exactly is a "tapestry program"? Anyway, do you know how to use JavaScript's `var` and `function` keywords? Start there.

Comment: @ChrisG Web application using tapestry. I guess semantics are your thing. Thank you for the wealth of knowledge and condescension you've shared. Gold star to you, not sure how I could have solved this without your invaluable help.

Comment: There's just no way to tell somebody they're missing the uttermost basic knowledge to achieve their goal without sounding condescending, is there?.  I didn't know about Apache tapestry (although I could've checked the tag description before asking), it was an honest question. Plus I did try and remain factual. I mean I could've told you that I absolutely dread the notion of actual people having to use this application in a work environment.